# Android eclipse dictionary code1

Tags: android

How to make dictionary on eclipse android?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take your time to learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this class:

```
HashMap<String, Object>
```

Create like this:

```
HashMap<String, Object> dictonary = new HashMap<>();
```

Add elements like this:

```
dictonary.put("key", "value");
```

Retreive elements like this:

```
dictonary.get("key");
```